# Installation failed: <!DOCTYPE html> 504 - Gateway Timeout

Tags: plugins, errors, curl

When installing the big plugins I am getting this error - WooCommerce. This problem does not happens with small plugins. It takes long time to install the plugin.

```
Installation failed: <!DOCTYPE html> 504 - Gateway Timeout * { box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; } body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; } .fit-wide { position: relative; overflow: hidden; max-width: 1240px; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 60px; padding-bottom: 60px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; } .background-wrap { position: relative; } .background-wrap.cloud-blue { background-color: #b0e0e9; } .background-wrap.white { background-color: #fff; } .title { position: relative; text-align: center; margin: 20px auto 10px; } .title--regular { font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif; } .title--size-large { font-size: 36px; line-height: 46px; } .title--size-semimedium { font-size: 20px; line-height: 28px; } .title--weight-normal { font-weight: 400; } .title--weight-bold { font-weight: 700; } .title--subtitle { padding-bottom: 40px; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial ,sans-serif; text-align: center; } .error h1, .error p { color: #226d7a; } .error--bg__cover { position: absolute; width: 100%; } .error--shape__clouds svg { display: block; } .abstract-half-dot--circle { z-index: 0; position: absolute; left: 15em; right: 0; width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto; } .icon-graphic { z-index: 1; position: relative; width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto; } @media screen and (max-width: 767px) { .error--bg__cover { display: none; } .abstract-half-dot--circle { left: 0; } } bg_error_lines circle_dots .st0{fill:#fff;} .st1{fill:#226D7A;} .st2{fill:#22B8D1;} 504 - Gateway Timeout This is a temporary error. Please try again later. clouds_shape
```

an another error that i faced is :

```
cURL error 18: transfer closed with 1075636 bytes remaining to read
```

This is with default clean wordpress and zero plugins

Is this an hosting error with CURL? Does wordpress downloads plugin with curl request?

Comment: how are you attemping to install the plugin?

Comment: @PaulG. WordPress way .. by going to add new

Comment: My guess is this is a temporary issue with your webhost and its connectivity to download ZIPs from WordPress.org. Or, and this is probably more likely, they've set a restrictive timeout in your configuration that's too short. Contact your host and tell them to increase your maximum request termination timeout. It's too short and it's killing your requests.

Comment: @PaulG.thank you, I am  contacting hosting